# Can't download on any browser after virus infection

Tags: browser

After virus removal, a machine I support is having issues downloading anything from the net using either IE or Chrome. Attempts to download bring up the browser's own warning bar to say it may be malicious or a virus and will go no further.

Today, it has manifested itself in another way: it won't allow downloads of files from Windows Live mail.

Any thoughts/suggestions ???

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Tech support questions are off topic here. I've voted to migrate this question to a more appropriate site. In the meantime, please read the [FAQ](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I disagree with you @Polynomial, this sounds like persistent malware, so relevant. I'm surprised you haven't used this to recommend NTSFO!

Comment: I'm confused. NTFSO?

Comment: Nuke The Site From Orbit, of course.

Comment: @GdD Okay, so we're doing that now? Home-brewed initialisms! Way to confuse new users even more.

Comment: @user26466 - Download the software on another computer, transfer to some external USB device or media of choice, and install the software.  Of course the computer is still infected with malware so the installation of another browser won't resolve that problem.

Answer (score 5):

Some malware exists to try and trick users into buying fake antivirus software, so it tells you that everything you try to do is a security threat. It is designed to mimic a system's messages as to fool users. It also may be re-directing the system's browser content to hacked sites, so it may be that the messages are authentic. This malware it typically very persistent - you think you've removed it but it keeps coming back. Unfortunately once a machine is infected with malware these days the only completely reliable way to recover is to completely wipe the affected system and re-install the OS and all applications. As @Polynomial would say, nuke the site from orbit.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you did not remove the virus, but it still is redirecting all downloads to a malicious download site. Your browsers could be correctly identifying the downloads as malicious because they are not from a valid source, even though you think you clicked on a valid link.

It looks like the machine should be wiped and restored from scratch.

Comment: Or better yet, restore from a backup.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the responses. After it failing to complete an SFC/Scannow I restored it to a week ago and am now able to download no problems. System file corruption?